# Share variables in xargs

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable, xargs

I have a function, say, *xfunc*, with something like this

```
xfunc() {
    # Infinite loop
    while :; do
        # Do some actions
        echo Hello
        # Counter??
    done
}
```

The question is how can I add the counter so that when I’ll use `seq 1 $parallels | xargs -P $parallels xfunc` it will share some variable or something with the others processes from xargs

My current version is `count=$(( $(<$counter_path) + 1 )); echo $count > $counter_path`, but it’s not very good because for some unknown reasons counter jumps through many nubers, gets back and do many strange things

So is there a way to make a public variable that every process could read and override, or any other better way to implement a counter?

Comment: If the processes run in parallel, they can overwrite each other's output if they all write to the same file.

Comment: Yes, they can, but as I said in question they overwrite it not in order. Of course I can add `[[ $my_count > $count ]] && echo $my_count > $count_path`, where *my_count* will be a local variable for every process, but I think there must be a better way for that purpose

Comment: Can you provide a simple, practical example of what you're trying to do? Show us a function that actually tries to do something (preferably not in infinite loop but limited loop), that already includes your current count code, and show the output of you command when `parallels`=2 or 3, just so we'll understand what your use case is, and where did you get stuck.

Comment: That's how parallel processing works. Reading of the initial value can happen in an order different to the order of writing; some processes can read the same input value, some processes can read a value written by another process.